# Hibernate: Mapping many-to-many without a join table

Tags: hibernate

Consider the following 2 tables in my database:

```
FUNCTION_TABLE

FUNC_CD     |   INPUT_ATTR_ID   |   OUTPUT_ATTR_ID
multiply    |   1               |   3
multiply    |   2               |   3
multiply    |   4               |   6 
multiply    |   5               |   6

ATTRIBUTE_TABLE

ATTR_ID     |   ATTR_NAME
1           |   AttributeOne
2           |   AttributeTwo
etc
```

My Function class should contain the following:

```
public class Function {
    private String functionCode;
    private Set<Attribute> inputAttributes;
    private Attribute outputAttribute;
}
```

My Function DAO then will contain a method that returns a Function object for the specified outputAttribute

How do I map this? Any examples I see require a join table for collections.

My mapping contains the following so far:

```
<class name="my.Function" table="FUNCTION_TABLE">
    <id name="functionCode" column="FUNC_CD" type="java.lang.String" />
    <many-to-one name="outputAttribute" class="my.Attribute" column="OUTPUT_ATTR_ID"/>
</class>
```

However, I'm at a loss on how to map the input attributes as  requires another table

Answer (score 0):

since this is a nonstandard way to represent this in the database hibernate does not support this ootb.

### Option 1:

```
// Function as wrapper around parts

Function getFunction(String code, Attribute outattr)
{
    List<FunctionPart> parts = session.createCriteria(FunctionPart.class)
        .add(Expression.eq("functionCode", code))
        .add(Expression.eq("outputAttribute", outattr))
        .list()

    return new Function(code, outattr, parts);
}
```

pro: simple
con: a function per query, additional class, no querying on inattributes

### Option 2:

make function a fake entity and depend on the attributes

```
<class name="my.Function" table="FUNCTION_TABLE" schemaction="none" where="todo INPUT_ATTR_ID = (min INPUT_ATTR_ID of same id)">
    <id name="functionCode" column="FUNC_CD" type="java.lang.String" />
    <many-to-one name="outputAttribute" class="my.Attribute" column="OUTPUT_ATTR_ID"/>

    <sqlinsert>INSERT into TEMPTABLE</sqlinsert>
    <sqlupdate>INSERT into TEMPTABLE</sqlupdate>

    <set name="inputAttributes" class="my.Attribute" table="FUNCTION_TABLE" cascade="all">
      <key>
        <column name="FUNC_CD" />
        <column name="OUTPUT_ATTR_ID" />
      </key>
      <many-to-many class="Attribute" column="INPUT_ATTR_ID">
    </set>
</class>
```

pro: as you requested
con: hackish, unneeded join, temp table has to be created if not present